# How to convert Date in sql 05/04/207 as 4MAY2017

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using

> CONVERT(nvarchar, Date, 106)

it gives 04MAY2017
but i need 4MAY2017  FOR 04/05/2017
and                                                                     11MAY2017 FOR 11/05/2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `CONVERT(nvarchar, Date, 106)` gives `04MAY2017` and you if you want to remove the first character if it is `0` then you can use a `CASE` expression.

**Query**

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LEFT(CONVERT(nvarchar, Date, 106), 1) = '0' 
THEN RIGHT(CONVERT(nvarchar, Date, 106), LEN(CONVERT(nvarchar, Date, 106)) - 1)
ELSE CONVERT(nvarchar, Date, 106) END
FROM your_table_name;
```

Comment: is there other alternatives for this

Comment: @Raj : Which `RDBMS` are you using?

Comment: 2008 sql server

Answer (score 0):

You could check when day-in-month < 10 then remove first character.

```
SELECT  REPLACE(CASE 
            WHEN datepart(day,dateColumn) < 10 
            THEN STUFF(convert(nvarchar(20), dateColumn, 106), 1,1,'')
            ELSE convert(nvarchar(20), dateColumn, 106)
      END, ' ', '') AS dateText 
FROM yourTable
```